# tikz tangent arc between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made a terrible MSPaint illustration below to try and communicate what I'm looking to achieve. I have two circles of radius 0.4 located at (0,0) and (1,0), respectively. I am using TikZ.

I am trying to draw a smooth and symmetric arc (hand-approximated in red) subject to the following constraints:

1. The end-points are tangent to each circle and are located on the outer edge of the circle. The end-points are defined on each circle by the same 45deg polar angle(albeit, in opposite facing directions).
2. The mid-point is located at (0.5, 0.2) with a flat tangent.

It may be true that defining an arc according to the above requires additional constraints; if a symmetric pair of control points can also be included so I might play with the concavity that would also be ideal.

Eventually I will want to put the same curve on the underside of the two circles as well, and fill with color the area in between.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you want the connecting arc to be a true arc (part of a circle) or any Bezier curve?

Comment: @Symbol1: With the given constrains, it is not possible to make a true arc - but it is close.

Comment: It can be a true arc of an ellipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rbez}{0.08}
\filldraw[fill=yellow] (45:0.4)
        arc[start angle=45,end angle=-45,radius=0.4]
        .. controls +(45:\rbez) and +(180:\rbez) .. (0.5,-0.2)
        .. controls +(0:\rbez) and +(135:\rbez) .. ($(1,0)+(225:0.4)$)
        arc[start angle=225,end angle=135,radius=0.4]
        .. controls +(225:\rbez) and +(0:\rbez) .. (0.5,0.2)
        .. controls +(180:\rbez) and +(-45:\rbez) .. cycle;
\draw (45:0.4) arc[start angle=45,end angle=315,radius=0.4];
\draw ($(1,0)+(-135:0.4)$) arc[start angle=-135,end angle=135,radius=0.4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing, thank you

Answer (score 8):

With the `in` and `out` syntax you can set the angles explicitly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle[radius=0.4] (1,0) circle[radius=0.4];
 \draw[fill=blue] (-45:0.4)  arc[start angle=-45,end angle=45,radius=0.4] 
  to[out=-45,in=180] (0.5,0.2)
   to[out=0,in=-135] ([xshift=1cm]135:0.4) 
   arc[start angle=135,end angle=225,radius=0.4] to[out=135,in=0]
   (0.5,-0.2) to[out=180,in=45] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is result is not unique. Even if you demand symmetry, there are two parameters that you can vary, `in looseness` and `out looseness`. An overall looseness roughly corresponds to `\rbez` from [polyn's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575734), but you can actually introduce two of them.

Comment: thank you- this is also a very nice answer. the in/out syntax is new to me; this is good to know how to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to have the midpoint not exact at `(0.5,0.2)` but less than a line width below, the bridge can be drawn with arcs alone, and there is no extra tension parameter.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red]
 (45:0.4)
 arc[radius={sqrt(0.5)-0.4}, start angle=-135, end angle=-45]
 arc[radius=0.4, start angle=135, end angle=225]
 arc[radius={sqrt(0.5)-0.4}, start angle=45, end angle=135]
 arc[radius=0.4, start angle=-45, end angle=45];
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=0.4];
\draw (1,0) circle[radius=0.4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circles with bridge]